# Why is my text to voice reading out code instead of the message?

Tags: java, android

I have a text to voice feature in my app where if you tap on text, the device will read it out. However, when you tap it, it reads out code instead of what the message contains.

Here is the feature:

```
private TextToSpeech t1;
```

In my `onCreate()`:

```
t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });
```

and in my messages:

```
protected void populateView(View v, Message model, int position) {
    TextView messageText
    messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
    final String msgText = messageText.toString();
    messageTextRight.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            t1.speak(msgText.toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: because `msgText.toString()` is not the way to get the text entered into the textview

Comment: `t1.speak(msgText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko you are correct.

Comment: @Jay you are also correct. Thanks.